# Report file viewer for Magento 1

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, file-browser

Is there any file viewer for Magento 1.x ? 
I need something to browse var/report folder from admin, and see error details

That for admin users of Magento, to know what happen, and decide call or no to developers support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is simple extension you can use, to allow admin check report error files
http://www.xpscommerce.com/magento-admin-view-var-report-errors/

Browse var/report folder from UI admin.